# Fill inputs in Android WebView with Autofill framework?

Tags: android, webview, autofill

In our Android app login screen implemented as web-page opened in WebView. There are login/password inputs at that page - I want to fill them using Autofill framework (i.e with Bitwarden app).

In other apps/web-pages there is always popup from Bitwarden saying these fields could be autocompleted. This popup never appears in our login web-page.

What I have to do, to fill WebView inputs with Autofill? Some specific WebView settings? Or maybe input html tags must have some sort of hint for Autofill framework?

Answer (score 0):

You're right, you ought to update the html tags, especially inputType or type, idEntry, hint etc. Because for native apps, autofill framework provides the AssistStructure which includes the form-field data, but for webViews, developer has to provide appropriate autocomplete hints to be able to be identified by the autofill provider app like Bitwarden.